# How to enable mariadb10.5 on Amazon Linux 2 with "amazon-linux-extras" command

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2, amazon-linux-extras

Greeting all;

I have working with an EC2 instance of  Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10, SSD Volume Type (64-bit Arm). I need to install a mariadb version 10.5 on my instance

Goal: My goal is to install mariadb10.5 from the amazon repo.
Problem: This database package is listed as "available" when executing amazon-linux-extras list

```
 52  tomcat9                         available    [ =stable ]
 53  unbound1.13                     available    [ =stable ]
  _  mariadb10.5                     available    [ =stable ]
 55  kernel-5.10=latest              enabled      [ =stable ]
 56  redis6                          available    [ =stable ]
 57  ruby3.0                         available    [ =stable ]
 58  postgresql12                    available    [ =stable ]
 59  postgresql13                    available    [ =stable ]
 60  mock2                           available    [ =stable ]
 61  dnsmasq2.85                     available    [ =stable ]
* Extra topic has reached end of support.
```

However, I cannot "enable" the package to install.  Reading the man page didn't bring anything to light about the reason why or why not.

Clue: I noted that there was a " _" before the name of the package. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install 10.5.10-MariaDB using the following commands.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable mariadb10.5
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum install mariadb
```